# How to inherit from MainWindow in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to know how to do inheritance from MainWindow correctly.
For example, program has a mainwindow with combobox, I want have a class which do some operations on this combobox: for example fill the combobox.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class FillCombo;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

fillcombo.h

```
#ifndef FILLCOMBO_H
#define FILLCOMBO_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Fill { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class FillCombo:public MainWindow
{
public:
    FillCombo(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FillCombo();
private:
    Fill::MainWindow *f_ui;
};

#endif // FILLCOMBO_H
```

fillcombo.cpp

```
#include "fillcombo.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


FillCombo::FillCombo(QWidget *parent)
    : MainWindow(parent)
    , f_ui(new Fill::MainWindow) //Error: Allocation of incomlepete type
{

}

FillCombo::~FillCombo()
{

}
```

Why I have this error, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Do you understand what namespace do? Apparently not since you forward declared class in `Fill`namespace and defined it in global namespace, then used forward declared version which do not have a definition.

Comment: So why if I have a code:

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

then Ui::MainWindow * ui;

and in constructor list: ui(new Ui::MainWindow);

Error doesnt occur. What is the difference between this and that what you wrote?